# Table Row Not Staying Selected in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, uiappearance

I am styling the selected `tableView` cell of my app globally with the `UIAppearance` API like this:

```
let selectionView = UIView()
selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#56B9A5")
UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = selectionView
```

But unfortunately when I have a `UISplitViewController` with a master table and a detail view, the background color doesn't stay in place when it's selected:

[image]

If I comment out the above code, and rely on the default selection style, the row stays selected.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `selectionStyle` property of your cell is not set to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

Comment: Yeah, it's not set to that which is how I can see the default gray selection if I turn off my `UIAppearance` code.